# More than one RKObjectManager at a time (RestKit 0.10.3)

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I looked on stackoverflow and found this topic:

[More than one RKObjectManager at a time (RestKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198664/more-than-one-rkobjectmanager-at-a-time-restkit)

Unfortunately it is not anymore accurate with the current RetKit as the method:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/whatever" delegate:self]
```

returns a void.

So how can I distinguish the different objectLoaders in the method:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
```

Or is there a better method to have multiple requests with different URLs? As if I only use one manager, only the last requests call gets executed, and I need to set the manager manually to null to work the second time.

Any help on how to best manage multiple request calls in a short amount of time and to distinguish between them would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many different things I finally found the new equivalent in the documentation.

The trick is to use a block and assing the loader.userData inside the block:

```
[self.manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:filter usingBlock: ^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.userData = @"identifier";
        loader.delegate = self;
    }];
```

Where the self.manager just a normal RKObjectManager with appropriate mapping is.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have different delegates for different "loadObjects" calls?

Comment: Well this is certainly one solution, but what if the delegate needs to respond to multiple objectLoader requests differently?