# One Table View from Two API's

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, uitableview

Is there a way for me to **populate one `UITableView` with two separate web APIs**?  I'm sure there is, but I can't quite figure it out.

Currently I'm pulling perfectly from one web API; but I need to pull from a different one and then merge them into one `UITableView`.

(I'm using RestKit)

(Second API I'm trying to integrate is Instagram, and will pull pictures/text from a user account)

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // RestKit
    NSString *baseURL = @"http://api.firstwebsite.com/v1";
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    if (!manager) {
        manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:baseURL];
        manager.client.serviceUnavailableAlertEnabled = YES;
        manager.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
    } else {
        manager.client.baseURL = [RKURL URLWithString:baseURL];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

WebListViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"/something/?limit=100&something=%@&something=%@&apikey=xxxx", var1, var2]
    usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

            hArray = objects;

            [_tableView reloadData];

        };
        [loader.mappingProvider setMapping:[Fe mapping] forKeyPath:@"fe"];
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
            //NSLog(@"BodyAsString: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        };
    }];
}
```

I'm assuming I'll need to do something different in the `AppDelegate.m` with the `baseURL` since it will have two different base URLs.

Thanks!  Will post any extra code as needed!

**EDIT**

**Per alexandresoli answer here's what I've updated so far, but still need help on:**

WebListViewController.m

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@synthesize array;

- (void)callBothURLs {
    // Call both #1 and #2 URL, not sure what specific code goes here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self callBothURLs];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // This is what I currently have, was pulling from a `Headlines` `NSArray` from web #1
    return headlinesArray.count;
    // I believe I need to change it to this next line...
    //return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Not sure what to put here with the new `NSMutableArray`
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I already have my object mapping set up for the first website, so I can easily do that part for the Instagram API.  All my confusion/problems seem to be in the WebListViewController.  Anyway here is a sample of mapping.

Mapping.h

```
@interface Mapping : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Links *links;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headline;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;

@end
```

Mapping.m

```
@implementation Mapping

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"headline", @"headline",
         nil];
        [mapping hasMany:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}

@end
```

Comment: You can do two loading in WebListViewController, no need to do it in AppDelegate.

Comment: Ahh, is it better going forward to just do it in the `ViewController` instead of `AppDelgate` then?  Just wondering.  Thanks!

Comment: Do both web services return data of the same type? Should the results be _sorted_ or _presented successively_ (1st web results, then 2nd web results)?

Comment: @vokilam They are both JSON, and the results will be sorted (1st web results and 2nd web resulted together sorted by date).  Basically in each table view cell will be a image and one text label.  Does that help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that calls both urls and store the result for each url inside the same NSMutableArray using the method addObject.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

// for each object from URL 1, call [array addObject:object];

// for each object from URL 2, call [array addObject:object];
```

Use this array as the datasource for your tableview;

**Update as requested:**

- You can call your populateBothUrlsMethod from viewDidLoad.
- After that, use your normal uitableview datasource methods numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection with this new populated array.

**Update 2:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    _array = [NSMutableArray new];


    // fetch data from url 1
    NSArray *arrayUrl1 = [self fetchUrl1];


    // add url1 data to array
    for (NSString *str in arrayUrl1) {
        [_array addObject:str];
    }


    // fetch data from url 2
    NSArray *arrayUrl2 = [self fetchUrl2];

    // add url2 data to array
    for (NSString *str in arrayUrl2) {
        [_array addObject:str];
    }

}


- (NSArray *)fetchUrl1
{
    return [NSArray array];
}

- (NSArray *)fetchUrl2
{
    return [NSArray array];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // total number of objects in array
    return [_array count];
}
```

Comment: So create `-(void)callBothURLs`, inside of which I would put the code you posted?  From there, how would I go about using that array as the datasource, do I put it in the `viewDidLoad`?  Sorry, I'm sure what ever you are saying is spot on, I've just never done it and am trying to wrap my head around it.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I've understood so far, still not totally sure where to put the `NSMutableArray`.  Appreciate you continuing to help!

Comment: Also, do I need to ditch the code in my `AppDelegate` for the `baseURL` since I'm not using just one `API` anymore?

Comment: Thanks!  You rock, appreciate the help.  I'll try to figure out how to implement this.  In the meantime, I gave you the 50 bounty regardless!

Comment: Working on this, do I need to throw out all my `viewDidLoad` code and replace with this, or which parts are usable or not usable?  Trying to figure out which parts you'd suggest I replace, and which parts are fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Totally understand conceptually what you're trying to do here, but I'm trying to fit it with what I already have specifically-

Comment: How about you post your code on github to let others view what are your trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the `NSString *str in arrayUrl2` in your recommendation?  Trying to figure out what string you're suggesting I grab, the url?

Answer (score 1):

Almost A to Z explanation.

**Assumptions**

- both APIs have similar responses
- final result should be sorted
- items shouldn't be presented until both API calls finish loading

**Basic idea**

Use `NSMutableArray` to store result items. Start both API requests simultaneously and add result items into array in appropriate success blocks. When both API calls are finished, sort array and reload table.

**Performing API calls**

Perform API calls in your view controller (probably in `viewDidLoad`), not in `AppDelegate`. The basic example of RestKit object request can be found at [github page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#object-request). Let's name our API calls `callAPI1`, `callAPI2`. For example, `[self callAPI1]` has following steps:

- define *mapping* from API1 to result object
- define *response descriptor*
- create API *request* and specify base URL
- create *request operation* and implement completion blocks
- start operation

Try to use single class for result objects (you'll need to use different mappings for each API) to simplify sorting. [see below]

**Respond to API calls**

Now we need to know when both requests will finish, in order to reload table. Use a simple counter, which initially set to number of requests and decrements when each API call finishes.

Your method implementation might look like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *_items;
    NSInteger _numberOfPendingCalls;
}

- (void)loadItems 
{
    _numberOfPendingCalls = 2;
    [_items removeAllObjects];

    [self callAPI1];
    [self callAPI2];
}
```

In success block we decrement pending calls, add items and check for completion:

```
^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    _numberOfPendingCalls--;

    [_items addObjectsFromArray:result.array];

    if (_numberOfPendingCalls == 0) {
        [self sortAndDisplayItems];
    }
}
```

If mutable array contains instances of single class (or at least items have same property), you could use `NSSortDescriptor` for sorting:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[_items sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Where `name` is a property of your result object.

I've omitted table view delegate implementation because it is straightforward.

**Further steps**

If you want to use RestKit object manager and your API have different base URLs, you need to use multiple object managers, one for each API. Reference: [More than one RKObjectManager at a time (RestKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198664/more-than-one-rkobjectmanager-at-a-time-restkit/21828546#21828546)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!  **Assumptions:** All are correct.  **Basic idea:** I believe I'm following you here, and have this in my "Edit" as `array`.  **Performing API calls:** I think I'm following you here.  In my `WebListVC` I am making the call, but just using the `baseURL` set forth in the `AppDelegate` and appending on to it. How do you suggest I re-do that... remove code from `AppDelegate` and then add full URL to `WebListVC` code I already have?  Any other changes on that?  Also, I have the mapping all set up for API1 and am loading the `UITableView` perfectly w API1 right now.

Comment: **Respond to API calls:** This makes sense and I will implement it.  **Further steps:** This is kind of a big part of my whole question, and what I was asking how to do.  I linked over to your question and can't quite figure out how it meshes with my code I posted.  Like, do I basically just need 2 of those `RKObjectManager`s, of which I already have one for API1 in my `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Thanks so much, I up voted your answer because its helped me already, but I really need the latter parts (i.e. I already have API1 working...what code needed to add API2 in same `viewDidLoad` AND how to get both in `UITableView` together sorted by date.

Comment: I recommend you to start without object managers. I provided a link to an example in __Performing API calls__ section. Look into it carefully. Here is one more: http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/51-intro-to-restkit-mapping. `callAPI1` and `callAPI2` have _different_ object mappings and base URLs and _identical_ success blocks. I gave you the basic structure, just try to implement the methods. I cannot write code for you.

Comment: Thanks!  Not asking you to write code for me, appreciate the help.  I'll try to figure out how to implement this.  How do I give you the 50 bounty too?  I gave it to the other guy, but thought there was a way to give you 50 too?

Comment: Regardless, I'll place another bounty on this if need be to make sure it gets to you for the help you gave so far, thanks-

Comment: Also, in the meantime, I added my `Mapping` code in the **"Edit 2"** part of my answer, so you can see how much I do/don't understand about Object Mapping.  I think I understand a good bit of it, but reason for my question is can't finish out my `WebListViewController` due to lack of understanding mostly of just how to merge the two arrays.